# how to make a scroll link

Tags: html, css

i leave you a link: https://carrd.co/.
Nice, when you click on "What is card", the page "scroll" instead of sending you right there.
So, how can i code that?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly want to achieve, because you're already "jumping" to the section.. but I guess you want the the `scrolling` to be quick and not smooth?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is likely to be an [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment). The smooth transition can be achieved by setting the CSS property [`scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior).

### Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html {
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#heading3">Go to Heading 3</a>
    <h1 id="heading1">Heading 1</h1>
    <h1 id="heading2">Heading 2</h1>
    <h1 id="heading3">Heading 3</h1>
    <h1 id="heading4">Heading 4</h1>
    <h1 id="heading5">Heading 5</h1>
    <h1 id="heading6">Heading 6</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, yes i just did it,  I'm sorry I'm wrong. What i need is the "transition", so the page that moves as it takes you to the point indicated by the link.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I missed that. I added a style section that should do what you want.

Comment: @matteobleve did it work for you? You might want to clarify your question a bit and remove the link. Nobody needs that link.